# CMake: How to set a generator expression based on an option (and compiler/build configuration)

Tags: cmake

I've got the following generator expression working, which sets the `/GS` flag if the compiler is MSVC and it sets it for the build configurations `RelWithDebInfo` and `Release`:

```
target_compile_options(mytarget PRIVATE
  "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:       $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/GS>>
   $<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/GS>>")
```

Now I also want to let the user configure this, and I've added an `option`:
`option(MYTARGET_ENABLE_GS "Enable /GS" OFF)`

So now, I (obviously) want to enable the `/GS` flag *if* the user enabled this option, and if they did, I want to add it *if* the compiler is MSVC, and it should be added to the `Release` and `RelWithDebInfo` configurations.

This is pretty nested, and I can't seem to get it right. This is as far as I got:

```
target_compile_options(mytarget PRIVATE
  "$<$<BOOL:MYTARGET_ENABLE_GS>:
     $<$<CONFIG:Release>:       $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/GS>>
     $<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/GS>>>")
```

**Edit:** Fixed, see below.

I've had to use the `$<$<BOOL:...>>` because that "translates" the `option` (which can be on/off or true/false, to `0` or `1`, which the generator expression needs.
However above line doesn't work: It doesn't add (or not add) `/GS`.

I'd like to know:

<s>1) Where is my mistake? How to do this? And</s>

2. Stuff like this results in pretty convoluted nested expressions, that are really hard to read - imagine 6 months down the line reading that line of code again, even if it is documented. And it's so easy to misplace a `>` or something like that.
   I could probably use "manual" `if`s to make this more readable, but imagine having 5-10 of such options - writing an `if`/`end` with a `target_compile_options` inside results in like 15-30 lines of `if`/`end` code, which is also not very pretty to look at. What's the best way to do this?

**Edit:** I was nearly there. Variables have to be enclosed with `${...}` in generator expressions. So it's for example:

```
target_compile_options(mytarget PRIVATE
  "$<$<BOOL:${MYTARGET_ENABLE_GS}>:
    $<$<CONFIG:Release>:       $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/GS>>
    $<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/GS>>>")
```

and that works great.

Which still leaves point "2)", which I would be keen to getting insights on.

Answer (score 6):

When you generate a MSVC solution, the build type (Release, Debug, etc.) is unknown until you actually run the build. Thus, using  generator expression for that is correct.

But for the 2 other variables (does user set MYTARGET_ENABLE_GS to OFF and is generation performed for MSVC), they are resolved at configuration time. So, you don't have to check them in a generator expression. You could simply write:

```
if(MSVC AND MYTARGET_ENABLE_GS)
    target_compile_options(mytarget PRIVATE "$<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Release>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:/GS>")
endif()
```

This solution also uses `$<OR:?[,?]...>` generator expression to regroup under the same expression both cases you build in Release OR RelWithDebInfo

Comment: Removed the space between `OR`s operands as it led to `Parameters to $<OR> must resolve to either '0' or '1'` on CMake 3.19.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you may use `if` command, use it. Generator expressions are **not** replacement for `if` command.

Generator expressions allow to use conditions dependent on *build type*. Because on multi-configuration build systems, like Visual Studio, build type isn't known at configuration stage, you cannot use such condition in `if` command.

But generator expressions are *ugly*, so do not use them when it is not needed.

There is nothing bad in

```
if(MYTARGET_ENABLE_GS)
    target_compile_options(mytarget PRIVATE "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/GS>>$<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/GS>>")
endif()
```

If you want to check an option at the beginning, but create a target later, you may store generator expression in the variable, and use this variable later:

```
set(additional_options)

# Depending on parameters, add options to 'additional_options' list.
if(MYTARGET_ENABLE_GS)
    list(APPEND additional_options "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/GS>>$<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/GS>>")
endif()

if(<other option>)
   list(APPEND additional_options <...>)
endif()
# ...
target_compile_options(mytarget PRIVATE ${additional_options})
```

Answer (score 0):

CMake's documentation a generator expressions works if your config matches any configuration listed after `CONFIG:`, but I couldn't find the syntax documented anywhere. Trial and error show the following works correctly:

```
if(MSVC AND MYTARGET_ENABLE_GS)
    target_compile_options(mytarget PRIVATE "$<$<CONFIG:Release,RelWithDebInfo>:/GS>")
endif()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.